# Getting an error while configuring a maven project using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting an error while building a maven project using jenkins. I had given path for pom.xml and also set MAVEN_HOME path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJiUS.png)

if anyone has any idea about it please share, waiting for your response.

Comment: Can you enable debug logs by adding -X to your maven commandline ?

Comment: Hi, after adding -x , i am getting this error...

Comment: Parsing POMs
D:\Jenkins_Home\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\C_apache_maven D:\Jenkins_Home\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar D:\Jenkins_Home\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar D:\Jenkins_Home\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar 55851
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -x
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You are adding -X at wrong place. Use this like mvn clean test -X